# How to list the checkboxes in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to list all the checkboxes available in a webpage by displaying their Visible Text in  selenium using Java?

Comment: It's very easy. Just find elements by tag name.

Comment: Could you share HTML as well???

Comment: This is the Webpage http://www.mygrocerychecklist.com/ @SaurabhGaur

Answer (score 1):

For that website this should do

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type=checkbox]"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    if (checkboxes.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No Checkbox present in the page");
    } else {
        for (WebElement checkbox : checkboxes) {
            if (checkbox.isDisplayed()) {
                String text=(String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent.trim();", checkbox);
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }
```